# Enable or disable a button in powershell based on conditions?

Tags: powershell

I have a GUI with a bunch of buttons.

I want to get-netneighbor for a specific range of IP addresses. Well those IPs are related to the buttons on my GUI. 
My IP range is

1-12

25-26

50-51

So if I get-netneighbor and it returns 7 and 26 and 50

I want to set

```
$button7.enabled = $true

$button26.enabled = $true

$button50.enabled = $true
```

The rest are set to disabled by default.

Not sure how to approach this.

```
    $buttonarr = @('$Button1','$Button2','$Button3','$Button4','$Button5','$Button6','$Button7','$Button8','$Button9','$Button10','$Button11','$Button12','$Button25','$Button26','$Button50','$Button51')#0-15

foreach ($IPAddress in $getneighbor){

    $cropped = ([ipaddress] "$IPAddress").GetAddressBytes()[3] 

    if($buttonArr -contains '$Reg'+$cropped){
        $index = $buttonarr.IndexOf('$Reg'+$cropped)
        $buttonarr[$index].enabled = $true

    }      

}

$form.ShowDialog()
```

Error message is

`The property 'enabled' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.`

The current machine im testing on has devices

```
50
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

So these buttons should be enabled when I launch the GUI and the others should not be enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

- create Buttons and set them all to false
- loop over `$getneighbor` and set buttons to `Enabled = True`

which would give us this code:

```
# I assumed $getneighbor is an array of IPAddresses like this
$getneighbor = "10.0.0.9","10.0.0.24","10.0.0.51","10.0.0.164"

# Creating the Buttons
$Buttons = 1..12 + 25..26 + 50..51 | % {
    $Name = "Button" + $_
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = $Name ; Enabled = $false }
}

# Setting Buttons on enabled
foreach ($IPAddress in $getneighbor)
{
    $Last = $IPAddress.split(".")[-1]
    $Buttons | ? { $_.Name -eq ("Button" + $Last) } | % { $_.Enabled = $true }
}
```

This would create an array of Buttons like this:

```
PS C:\Users\SimonS> $Buttons

Name     Enabled
----     -------
Button1    False
Button2    False
Button3    False
Button4    False
Button5    False
Button6    False
Button7    False
Button8    False
Button9     True
Button10   False
Button11   False
Button12   False
Button25   False
Button26   False
Button50   False
Button51    True
```

You could then do this to get all enabled Buttons returned:

```
PS C:\Users\SimonS> $Buttons | ? { $_.Enabled -eq $true } | select -expand Name
Button9
Button51
```